# Address blocked by CONNECTION_REFUSED and SSL failure, blazor local network connect API

Tags: android, ssl, blazor, connection-refused

I have API ASP.NET Core in localhost and Client-side Blazor app at the same device. When I start API and Client local everythink work fine in PC browser, but I try start my app on mobile device (Client will be use only on mobile).

First I configure ***launchsettings.json*** for any device in local network. Add system policy to allow connection. I start API and Client at the PC and open Chrome on Android phone, open app by https://10.137.1.38:5002. App Client normal start but when I try connect to local API I have an error with CORS policy.

How configure CORS policy to allow connect local API to mobile device?

or

How to disable CORS policy? (delete services.AddCors(); not help)

Here is my code

Client

**launchsettings.json**

```
        "PMO_Blazor.UI": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5000;http://localhost:5001;https://*:5002;",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
```

**Program.cs**

```
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://10.137.1.38:44335/") });
```

**Call to api**

```
try
            {
                using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
                authResult = await _client.PostAsync($"/Authorization/login", content, tokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error.ErrorMess = "Server is not available";
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception  {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
```

API

***Services***

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
            options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithOrigins("https://localhost:5002", "https://localhost:44335")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
            });
            
            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
                options.HttpsPort = 44335;
            });
```

Open CORS in Configure

```
app.UseCors("Open");
```

Errors

[image: errors]

Comment: The .WithOrigins(..) part should probably include the 10.137.1.38:5002 address. Localhost is only known locally.

Comment: Doesn't help, when I remove all CORS policy its the same. I try add IP Android device too and the same error appears.

Comment: I see a lot of portnumbers, they don't all match up. And does your Android accept the certificate for 10.137.1.38?

Comment: The messages in the https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Qpj.png image show clearly that the cause has nothing at all to with your CORS config. No matter how you configure CORS settings, it’ll never case a `CONNECTION_REFUSED` error — nor an SSL failure. The https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Qpj.png messages seem to indicate a failure to establish any SSL connection, due to a certificate problem. The CORS message is just a side effect of the fact the browser never gets any response back — because the connection is refused due to the SSL problem before the server can process the request and send a response.

Comment: Thanks for reply @sideshowbarker, I try repair error SSL by tricky accept non safety connection on the mobile browser. I just type API address to browser and accept the risk. Error SSL disappear, but the CORS error it's still there. [error](https://i.imgur.com/8Fo82LN.png)